# Spark - how to use function in where condition?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am tryint to use avg (`f.avg("age")`) as the condition as bellow.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
...
...
(
titanic
    .where("Survived = 1")
    .where(f.col("age") > f.avg("age"))
    .groupBy('Sex','Pclass')
    .count()
    .show()
)
```

But it not works. How can I do it?

Something similar using spark sql (works):

```
spark.sql("""
    select sex, Pclass,count(*) from titan where Survived = 1 
    and age > (select avg(age) from titan) group by sex,Pclass
""").show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compute the average first. I assume you want the average age for `('Sex','Pclass')`. You can change that

```
(
titanic.withColumn('avg_age',mean('age').over(Window.partitionBy('Sex','Pclass')))
    .where("Survived = 1")
    .where(f.col("age") > f.col("avg_age"))
     
    .groupBy('Sex','Pclass')
    .count()
    .show()
)
```

Comment: Not working in spark 3.3.1: NameError: name 'Window' is not defined. Is there some module I need to load first to use Window?

Comment: from pyspark.sql.functions import *

Comment: Thanks, actually it was missing "from pyspark.sql import Window". Also, average is for all the people, independently of sex or pclass as the SQL: "select avg(age) from titan". How can I do this in your example?

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it helped you in anyway

Comment: Hi, it has helped me in certain way, but still don't undestand how to compute average for all the people, independently of sex or pclass as the SQL I show before.

Comment: Ok, groupby nothing as follows `titanic.withColumn('avg_age',mean('age').over(Window.partitionBy())).show()`

Comment: Thanks for your time, it has worked. Please edit the question with the last comment ^^